# Where does OS X keep the FileVault password during reboots in an upgrade?

Tags: macos, security, password, filevault

For security concerns, I wonder how it would be possible for an OS X upgrade (e.g. from Mavericks to El Capitan), to reboot my Mac multiple times without asking me for my FileVault 2 password?

I mean, the whole drive is encrypted and even an OS X installer would not know the password after a reboot. In spite of that, it reboots one or more times without asking me for my password.

Therefore I suspect that Apple stores my password somewhere, either on disk, in NVRAM, or online, at least during the upgrade process. If so, wouldn't this be a serious security concern?

Can anyone shed a bit of light on this? How does it work?

Comment: As an aside, OS X accidentally logged the password in plaintext to disk during a 10.7.3 upgrade: http://9to5mac.com/2012/05/07/bug-in-mac-os-x-10-7-3-exposes-passwords-in-plain-text/ ! It has since been fixed, of course.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

There's an OS X feature called [authenticated restart](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202918) that stores the FileVault key in the SMC for the duration of the reboot. Apple acknowledges [in the manpage](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/fdesetup.8.html) that it does reduce FileVault security for the duration of the restart:

> On supported hardware, `fdesetup` allows restart of a FileVault-enabled system without requiring unlock during the subsequent boot using the `authrestart` command.
>
> WARNING: FileVault protections are reduced during authenticated restarts.
>
> In particular, `fdesetup` deliberately stores at least one additional copy of a permanent FDE (full disk encryption) unlock key in both system memory and (on supported systems) the System Management Controller (SMC).  `fdesetup` must be run as root and itself prompts for a password to unlock the FileVault root volume.  Use `pmset destroyfvkeyonstandby` to prevent saving the key across standby modes. Once `authrestart` is authenticated, it launches `reboot(8)` and, upon successful unlock, the unlock key will be removed.

Comment: Thanks. Perfectly answers my question and reduces my concerns to the question whether erasure from SMC is actually complete and safe.